# Duplicate Values from Another Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am setting up a database with hundreds of product names and I need an easy way to copy search volume from another list in the same spreadsheet.

I have tried to use:

```
=vlookup(lower(A1),$E$1:$F$5,2,false)
```

And I also looked at all Google documentation on Google Docs but none of the formulas was successful to achieve my goals.

```
=vlookup(lower(A1),$E$1:$F$5,2,false)
```

I am expecting the raws in column B to be based on the raws from column F.

I have uploaded links to the desired result:

Document - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzIy30AoK4hu3Sz3u_08k8DNMA2dXmAyc3xFhn3gCzU/edit#gid=0

Video screencast - https://streamable.com/peu3w

Screenshot - [image: https://imgur.com/a/mYDoN61]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't need to define `LOWER`. all you need is `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, E:F, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This solved my issue, I am very thankful for your help. God bless and take care. I am not sure who downvoted you, this really did fix my stuff. Thank you and good luck in everything you do!